# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined" and other

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to send a message to a specific channel and option is not working for me. Below easiest command to test this:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const channel = message.channels.cache.get('458524389936201730');
    channel.send('test');
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: "xxx"
};
```

I received bug like this or I received other bugs similar to this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
```

Changing "message" to "bot" in const variable doesn't help :(

Comment: that would indicate that `message.channels` is undefined - perhaps you need to show HOW you're calling the function

Comment: Yes, maybe a jsFiddle or something we can work with, would be nice ...
Otherwise it is hard to understand the context.

Is this from the discrod but guide?

Answer (score 0):

The `Message` object does not have a `channels` property. You should, instead, be using the `Guild` object that is a property of the message object, and that includes a channels property.

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('458524389936201730');
    channel.send('test');
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: "xxx"
};
```

Comment: This assumes the module is run within a guild and that the bot has permissions to send messages. It will throw an error otherwise.

Comment: Considering most command handlers nowadays take care of both of those problems (assuring that the message was sent in a guild and that the bot has enough permissions), I believe this answer is valid unlike what you are suggesting it to be.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too generic and I can't really help if you don't provide more details as to what is the expected outcome.

I can see 2 ways you may want this to work:

1. If you want to send a message to channel with specific ID:

```
   module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
        const channel = message.guild?.channels.resolve('458524389936201730');
        channel.send('test').catch();
    };
```

2. If you want to send a message to the same channel:

```
    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
        message.channel.send('test').catch();
    };
```